# python import std output to a new file

Tags: python

I have a set of print stmts which is printed when i run in python shell,but i wanted to save them in a file without changing the order of output as it was in shell output.

I have a part of file having print stmts,i have to save them into a new file:

```
with open('myfile') as f:

            print best1
            print best2   
            s1 = ('best1'+'best2')
            print s1
with open('newfile') as f: #<-dont know how to display in newfile for above print stmts
```

How do i save them into a new file without changing the order of the output?

Answer (score 1):

The "print" statement writes to stdout by default. You can still use it to write to other destinations, however.

Old style:

```
with open("/tmp/testme.txt", "w") as fo:
    print >>fo, "some text."
```

New style:

```
from __future__ import print_function

with open("/tmp/testme.txt", "w") as fo:
    print("some text.", file=fo)
```

The latter is what you would use in Python 3, (or 2 with the `__future__` import, which you leave out in 3).